# Power BI Divide the value of a row with a value from another row in Matrix report

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, divide

[image: my table]

I want to divide each bold row (rows with indices 1, 4 7, 11) with the value in the 11th row (Total Volume row).

For example, for the first row, I want to calculate 12.921.939,87 / 3.542.787,69

This is my data:
[image: my data]

Comment: The data does not match your report. How do you calculate those values in the report? Also the names of Attribute are different in report and in data. Is it really this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a measure similar to the following. Just change the `"b"` part with `"Total Volume (Ton)"`

```
DividedBySumOfAttributeB = 
VAR _denom = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Value]),ALL(Table1),Table1[Attribute]="b")
RETURN SUM(Table1[Value]) / _denom
```

Resulting matrix:
[image]

This is my sample data:
[image]